# Is their any alternative way for resource filtering to work with Maven for spring boot application?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

I am working on a spring boot application using Maven as a build tool in which I was trying to use resource-filtering with Maven. It does not seem to work as it works for other spring projects. How can I accomplish it?

I have used spring-boot-starter as the parent in my pom. I have myconfig.properties file in src/main/resource folder. I have one of the properties in myconfig.properties file like this:

```
prop.first=@project.version@
```

Here @ is the spring-boot default token filter that should be used instead of $.

```
<project>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
     </parent>

    <version>19.6.0</version>
    ......
    <build>
        .....
        <resource>
            <directory>/src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/myconfig.properties</include>
            </includes>                
        </resource>
        .....
    </build>
    .....
</project>
```

Since the "project.version" in my case is 19.6.0, on building with maven, I was expecting prop.first in myconfig.properties file to be:

```
prop.first=19.6.0
```

But on actual, the property is never replaced and is still same in file as:

```
prop.first=@project.version@
```

I read somewhere in the documentation which says maven filtering is not applied on src/main/resources in spring boot. While the same filtering with maven works for other types of projects than spring-boot, what can be the alternative way to do resource filtering in my case?

Comment: Check your myconfig.properties file path, try by placing your **myconfig.properties**  file inside **resources** folder and update include as **<include>myconfig.properties</include>** , this might work.

Comment: @SelvamM That's where myconfig.properties already exists.

Comment: Change your <include> tag value like <include>myconfig.properties</include> it works for me.

Comment: @SelvamM It helped. Thanks